# Buttons from Main Activity to Fragment(ViewPage)?

Tags: android, fragment

So I have 2 important element in my MainActivity, a button, and an edittext field. I want to make my buttons only visible at the third fragment page, how to do that? Here's my code.

DeviceFragment.java

```
package com.danmarker.decideforme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Laptop on 2015.03.17..
 */
public class DeviceFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ImageIDKey = "imagekey";
    public static final String DescriptionKey = "descriptionkey";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();


        if(bundle != null)
        {
            int imageID = bundle.getInt(ImageIDKey);
            String description = bundle.getString(DescriptionKey);

            setValues(view, imageID, description);
        }
        return view;
    }


private void setValues(View view, int imageID, String description) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDevice);


    imageView.setImageResource(imageID);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceDescription);
    textView.setText(description);
}
}
```

DevicePagerAdaptor.java

```
package com.danmarker.decideforme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Laptop on 2015.03.18..
 */
public class DevicePagerAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] devices;
    String[] deviceDescription;

    public DevicePagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fn, Context context) {
        super(fn);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        devices = resources.getStringArray(R.array.devices);
        deviceDescription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.device_description);

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(DeviceFragment.DescriptionKey, deviceDescription[position]);
        bundle.putInt(DeviceFragment.ImageIDKey, getDeviceImageID(position));

        DeviceFragment deviceFragment = new DeviceFragment();
        deviceFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return deviceFragment;
    }

    private int getDeviceImageID(int position) {

        int id = 0;
        switch (position) {


        }
        return id;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return devices.length;
    }
```

The problem is, that the buttons in the MainActivity are overlay on the fragment, so they are visible, no matter how I'm swiping the screen. I want to make them visible only, when I get to the last fragment.
How to do that? I have a fragment_device.xml also, I have to declare the buttons in the DeviceFragment, or what? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Why don't you make the buttons part of the third fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ViewPager`, you can register a `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` and use the `onPageSelected` method to show your `Button`.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int index) {
        if (index == 2) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the position inside the bundle argument and based on the position you get show the button in the fragment